# how to convert thrift TCompactProtocol to TBinaryProtocolTransport

Tags: python, api, line, thrift

I have a api made based on thrift TCompactProtocol.

Is there a quick way to convert it into TBinaryProtocolTransport?
Is there a tool for conversion?

FYI. My api is Line Api bases api Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tool needed. Since yyou did not elaborate on your actual use case too much, I can only give a generic answer.

### You control both RPC server & client + we do NOT talk about stored data

In that case you need only to replace the transports on both ends and you're pretty much done.

### All other cases

You will need two pieces

- a piece of code that deserializes old data stored with "compact"
- a piece of code that deserializes these data using "binary"

Both cases are not really hard to implement technically.

Comment: thaks for you answer, thats work  

Comment: Upvoting and/or accepting answers works even better ;-)